# Sublime Automatically build New Build System

Tags: macos, sublimetext2

I have a js and html build system on sublime .  I'd prefer not to have to switch my build system anytime I want to compile in those languages.  Is there a way I can make the automatic build system choose html whenever the file has a .html suffix?  Right now this is all I have in my html build system

```
"cmd": ["open", "-a", "Google Chrome", "$file"]
```

I'm running Mac OS 10.9.5.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your build system to this:

```js
{
    "cmd": ["open", "-a", "Google Chrome", "$file"],
    "selector": "text.html"
}
```

Next, go to **`Tools -> Build System`** and select **`Automatic`**. Now, whenever you're editing an HTML file, you can hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> and it will automatically use your HTML build system. You can read all about build systems [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) and [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html).

Comment: @user3204416 glad I could help. If my answer helped solve your problem, you may choose to mark your question as "resolved" by clicking the check mark next to the answer. Please see [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more details.